# xcode update tableview after assigning new value to predicate (by pressing button)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, tableview, predicate

Hi I have been trying to code a data entry iOS app.

Each entry basically contain startTime, duration and some other contents.

Basically I got a ViewController ( that contains a table View) for reporting purpose.

The intended function is that the report would display all entries in the selected month.

The user select the month by pressing previous/next button.

As by now when I enter the page, all entries of current month are being displayed (as intended).

However, whenever I press the previous button, the tableview just gone blank.

```
- (IBAction)previousPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.components setMonth:-1];
    self.rangeStart = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:self.components
                  toDate:self.rangeStart options:0];

    self.rangeEnd = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:self.components
                 toDate:self.rangeStart options:0];

    ////what next
}
```

As you may have guess the value of self.rangeStart AND self.rangeEnd are being used for setting up the predicate.  ( And it works for the first time around, for showing the default the month's entries)

I have tried quite something else below but most of the time the tableView will just go blank after the button is pressed. I basically have no idea what to put below it.

Things that I have tried:  (all in the what next area)

```
[self loadView];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Another one:

```
SLCoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [SLCoreDataStack defaultStack];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];


_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]       
initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext 
sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
```

As i thought these are the related codes that do the fetching at first.

More details about my code:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

Basically it all starts from performing this in ViewDidLoad, which leads to fetchedResultsController that contains the second section of codes i gave.

For the entryListFetchRequest I basically just get the entity and set the below predicate

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"start >= %@ && start <= %@",     self.rangeStart, self.rangeEnd];
```

I thought I just need to fetch it again with the new predicate, hence I tried [self loadView]. 
Is this related to controllerWillChangeContent / didChangeObject and leading to beginUpdates part?

(Tell me if more details would be preferable)

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.components setMonth:-1];
```

You set the month to -1. Months can be 1 up to 12.

```
self.components.month -= 1;
```

might work. But better take the Value (NSInteger if my memory serves right), modify it and then write it back.

```
NSInteger month = self.components.month;
if (month > 1) {
month--;
} else {
month = 12;
NSInteger year = self.components.year;
year--;
self.components.year = year;
}
self.components.month = month;
```

This covers the case when the month is January and u want December previous year.

Comment: Actually I have been checking it with NSLog and the values have been properly decreased by a month there.  ( might double check it later on)